# issue in laravel relationship with multiple model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

**user has relation with creater one to one but creater has relation with archive belongsToMany**

```
$creatorQuery = User::query();
    $cultivator_id = 2;
    $creatorQuery = $creatorQuery->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'role');

    $creatorQuery = $creatorQuery->with('creater', function($q) {
        $q->whereHas('archive', function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
            $query->where('caltivater_id', $cultivator_id);
        });
    });

    $creators = $creatorQuery->get();
```

*showing error mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to get all users who have `caltivater_id = $cultivator_id` in related `archive` model?

Comment: yes but when we try multiple relation we found this  error mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 0):

`function` is supposed to be passed into `creater`, so you need to change your call to be a key/value array:

```
$creatorQuery = $creatorQuery->with(['creater' => function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
    $q->whereHas('archive', function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
        $query->where('caltivater_id', $cultivator_id);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: showing this error Undefined variable: cultivator_id

Comment: but show all  record not check $query->where('caltivater_id', $cultivator_id); condition

Answer (score 0):

You've said you want to get users by their `caltivater_id` value defined in `Archive` model. Use nested [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$creators = User::whereHas('creator', function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
    $q->whereHas('archive', function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
        $q->where('caltivater_id', $cultivator_id);
    });
})
->with('creators')
->get();
```

Or use dot notation:

```
$creators = User::whereHas('creator.archive', function($q) use($cultivator_id) {
    $q->where('caltivater_id', $cultivator_id);
})
->with('creators')
->get();
```